# Java: Can't get my main method to work

Tags: java, exception, program-entry-point

I'm using Fedora and I have had some issues to get javac to work (I finally succeeded by making an alias). But now I can't execute my java code. I get the error in the title.
Here is the class that contains the main method:

```
public class test
{
    public static void main(String args)
    {
       int res[]= {4,2,6};
       res=Trieur.tri(res);
       for(int i: res)
          System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

I've been trying a lot of solutions in this forum but none seems to work. The program compiles successfully.
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change this:

`public static void main(String args[])`

Answer (score 4):

Or as `public static void main(String[] args)`. Either syntax is valid in Java, although this format is arguably slightly more popular.